# PHP code should not get change

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to make an plugin in WP. There is a license.php file where some code (Specified some URLs) should not get change by any other user.

Is there any way to prevent that once the code goes to the client's server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to prevent other developers from changing your code? This can be done in PHP with encryption or with obfuscation. Neither will abide by WordPress license, GPL. How can make your code work like a service by providing an API to do what your module does but on your own servers.
If that solution is not viable I don't think there is a solution. If someone wants to change php code, they will.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prevent other developers from changing my code. We have our own server where we have installed 'software license Manager' plugin.. Now I am trying to interact with the software license manager API in my another plugin which should not get change..